# Duplicate a column with Laravel

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel I am some data that follow the same model. I would like to duplicate.

I tryed this code :

```
public function duplicate($id)
    {
        $vpn = Vpns::findOrFail($id);
        $newVPN = $vpn->replicate();
        $newVPN->save();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }
```

Problem is just date some datas are duplicate but not 100%. I have a new entry but 80% of data of precedent model are duplicated.

Example : text data are duplicated but not checkbox values or something like that.

DO you have some ideas ?

Thanks

[image: database]

Comment: Can you share your table structure and an example record and how the replicated one looks like in the database?

Comment: its added. on the left you dont see its just id of product etc... on the right this is the important : the values I want duplicate easily

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This

```
public function duplicate($id)
{
    $vpn = Vpns::find($id);
    $newVPN = $vpn->replicate();
    $newVPN->save();
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I dont see the difference. Can you explain please ?

Comment: what are the data type of those columns where it is not inserting? can you try this `$vpn->replicate()->save();`